# How to solve Firmware Bug (TSC_DEADLINE disabled)?

Tags: microcode

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 with kernel 4.13. In `dmesg` I can see

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x700000e (or later)
```

I installed latest intel-microcode (3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0) and microcode.ctl (1.18~0+nmu2). After reboot I could see in `dmesg`

```
[Пт окт  6 15:37:25 2017] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x700000e (or later)
[Пт окт  6 15:37:25 2017] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x700000d, date = 2016-10-12
```

How can I get microcode 0x700000e?

Comment: File a bug report against the intel-microcode package and see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1700373